# SQL join 4 tables

Tags: mysql

```
(SELECT s.sid, s.sname, e.ccode
FROM student s INNER JOIN enrolled e 
ON s.sid = e.sid
WHERE s.programme = 'IT')
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT c.ccode, c.tid
FROM class c INNER JOIN tutor t
ON c.tid = t.tid
WHERE t.tname = 'Hoffman');
```

This is what i've got so far, doesn't work though. Need to get the names of IT students from the student table that are enrolled in a class by a tutor named Hoffman, all from the enrolled, class and tutor tables.
where am i going wrong?

Class:

```
ccode   | cname         | weekday | meets at | room  | tid
________________________________________________________________________
CIS166  | Intro to Comp | Tue     | 10:00:00 | MB300 | 1
________________________________________________________________________
CIS177  | Maths         | Mon     | 15:00:00 | MB100 | 6
________________________________________________________________________
CIS188  | Info Syst     | Thu     | 14:00:00 | MB230 | 5
________________________________________________________________________
CIS199  | Intro to Java | Fri     | 10:00:00 | MB300 | 4
________________________________________________________________________
CIS277  | Algorithmics  | Thu     | 14:00:00 | MB200 | 2
________________________________________________________________________
CIS288  | Database Syst | Mon     | 14:00:00 | MB142 | 1
________________________________________________________________________
CIS297  | Web Design    | Mon     | 16:00:00 | MB109 | 3
________________________________________________________________________
CIS298  | C++           | Fri     | 10:00:00 | MB110 | 8
```

Tutor:

```
tid | tname
_____________________
1   | Rob Hoffman
_____________________
2   | James Butler
_____________________
3   | Kathy Bond
_____________________
4   | Theodora Stewart
_____________________
5   | Mike Richie
_____________________
6   | John Kay
_____________________
7   | Mary Tregear
_____________________
8   | Mark Robinson
```

Enrolled:

```
sid | ccode
______________
211 | CIS288
203 | CIS298
214 | CIS297
105 | CIS177
215 | CIS297
104 | CIS188
210 | CIS297
338 | CIS320
102 | CIS177
338 | CIS399
204 | CIS288
204 | CIS277
102 | CIS199
203 | CIS297
105 | CIS199
331 | CIS320
202 | CIS299
205 | CIS299
210 | CIS298
331 | CIS399
321 | CIS399
210 | CIS288
210 | CIS277
204 | CIS297
321 | CIS320
328 | CIS388
327 | CIS388
211 | CIS297
333 | CIS399
215 | CIS288
104 | CIS199
```

Student:

```
sid | sname        | programme | level | age
____________________________________________
101 | Lorry Ross   | CS         | 1     | 18
102 | Lydia Ken    | CIS        | 1     | 18
103 | Bob Chung    | CS         | 1     | 18
104 | Sonia Morris | CIS        | 1     | 18
105 | Mark Poppy   | CS         | 1     | 19
106 | Megan Chi    | IT         | 1     | 20
218 | Diana McDon  | IT         | 2     | 20
219 | Nick Smith   | IT         | 2     | 21
```

Comment: Please show us the table structures (with the fields which are sufficient for the query). Now your two parts of the query have no linked fields and it is hard to suggest where they do exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing your schema, this is a guess, but should point you in the right direction:

```
select s.sid, s.sname, e.ccode 
from student s
inner join enrolled e on s.sid = e.sid 
inner join class c on e.ccode = c.ccode --may be incorrect
inner join tutor t on c.tid = t.tid 
where s.programme = 'IT'
    and t.tname = 'Hoffman'
```

Comment: again this brings up selected column headings but no results?

Comment: That's not surprising, because there is not tutor named 'Hoffman' in the example data.

Answer (score 2):

I would work the query in reverse from what Red offered... You know the tutor, and drill into for that person's students...  If one tutor is associated with say... 3 classes, why query a table of possibly 10,000 students

```
select
      s.id,
      s.sname,
      e.eccode
   from
      tutor t
         join class c
            on t.tid = c.tid
            join enrolled e
               on c.ccode = e.ccode
               join students s
                  on e.sid = s.sid
                 and s.programme = 'IT'
   where
      t.tname = 'Hoffman'
```

Comment: This brings up the selected column headings, but no results.

Comment: I would assume that the query planner will take the actual tables into account by itself and will decide the access order to the tables by itself. For this example there should be no difference between RedFilter's way and your way.

Answer (score 1):

Your query doesn't work because there's no relationship expressed in the `exists` block with the top select statement. You need to find a way to relate the `tutor` and `class` tables back to the `student` and `enrolled` tables. In other words, you should be able to express your whole query using merely `inner joins` between the 4 tables and the appropriate where clauses.